# PostgreSQL function string concatenation

Tags: postgresql

Problem:
Function takes a spatial clause as a parameter of text (more about this later) and appends to the primary sql string.

```
    clause = '((44<=NeLon AND 45>=SeLon AND 37<=NeLat AND 38>=SwLat) OR 
    (SwLon<=45 AND NeLon>=44 AND SwLat<=38 AND NeLat>=37))'
```

Note the following function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _fconcat(area integer DEFAULT 100, pdate date 
    DEFAULT '2018-01-01', acc real DEFAULT 50.0, clause text DEFAULT NULL)
        RETURN SETOF temporary.myschema AS
    $BODY$
            DECLARE sqmtokm CONSTANT integer DEFAULT 1000000;
                    sql text;             
    BEGIN
        SELECT CONCAT ('SELECT * from temporary.myschema WHERE ', ST_Area(ST_GeogFromWkb(geom))\', 'sqmtokm <= ', area, ' AND 
        productdate >= ', pdate, ' AND accuracy <= ', acc, ' AND ',  clause, ';') AS sql;
            RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
   END;$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
   SET search_path = public;
```

am specifically concerned with the following.

- a) the sql variable is being executed to generate the SETOF table rows
  results
- b) I'm using the CONCAT function to amalgamate the string
  components to build the sql string but not sure if is the best
  approach.
- c) my clause parameter is of type "text" rather than
  character varying is this ok
- d) I am receiving an error stating that

> "sql" is NULL at" RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql

my primary issue is **being able to concatenate an SQL SELECT command and execute it returning a set of table rows.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed Answer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _fconcat(area integer DEFAULT 100, pdate date 
DEFAULT '2018-01-01', acc real DEFAULT 50.0, clause text DEFAULT NULL)
    RETURN SETOF temporary.myschema AS
$BODY$
        DECLARE sqmtokm CONSTANT integer DEFAULT 1000000;
                sql text;             
BEGIN
    sql := 'SELECT * from temporary.myschema WHERE ' || ST_Area(ST_GeogFromWkb(geom))\' || 'sqmtokm <= ' || area || ' AND 
    productdate >= ''' || pdate, ''' AND accuracy <= ' || acc, ' AND ' || clause AS sql
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
SET search_path = public;
```

Will gladly accept any other input.  My understanding to make this bullet proof is I should be using the [`USING`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146245/2712652) command to prevent SQL injection.